# On some equivalences of $\omega$-categoricity.

Tags: model-theory

Let $T$ be a complete theory without finite models. Prove that the following are equivalent:

1. $T$ is $\omega$-categorical.
2. $T$ has a countable model which is both atomic and saturated.
3. All models of $T$ are $\omega$-saturated.

I already proved that if $T$ is $\omega$-categorical then $T$ has a countable model which is atomic - by a straigforward argument involving prime model -; nevertheless, the remaining saturated condition is missing. Also, I'm having problems on the rest of the exercise.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: a theory is countably categorical iff there are finitely many $n$-types for each $n$ (this is (a part of) the Ryll-Nardzewski theorem). This implies that there are finitely many types over any finite set. See that this implies that every model is $\omega$-saturated.

You may want to use omitting types theorem.

Comment: Thanks; any advice on the other parts ??

Comment: I already manage to prove almost everything. It just remain 3. implies 1., any advice ??

Comment: @user248653: As I have said, omitting types is crucial here.

Comment: Yes, I have the intuiting that I must use it; but I can't see precisely how.

Comment: @user248653: A saturated model cannot omit a type. An infinite compact space has a non-isolated point. Alternatively, any two saturated models of the same cardinality are isomorphic.